# Product dimensions visible on product configuration page

Tags: magento2, attributes, attribute-set, dimensions

How to get these attributes visible on product configuration page?

> **ts_dimensions_height
>
>   ts_dimensions_length
>
>   ts_dimensions_width**

I already added them to my attribute-set, set **'Visible'** everywhere in attribute settings, but still, have it invisible on the product configuration page. Other attributes from the set are visible.